# Doesn't run new docker image

Tags: docker

I start from a Ubuntu standard image and I have installed python 2.7, after with the command `docker commit b984c5309ee7 ubuntu_python` I have created a new image but when I run the command `docker run ubuntu_python` the docker doesn't start.
The original image works properly, the copy doesn't start and I don't see any error message.

From a newbie
Thanks

Comment: Please provide a [mre] demonstrating the issue.  This should include the exact commands you ran, including whatever you did inside the running container.  As @SoftwareEngineer notes, using `docker commit` at all makes the "reproducible" part of this much harder.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `docker commit` -- that's a really advanced technique for very rare use-cases that should be avoided. You should be writing a `Dockerfile` and using `docker build` instead. As it stands, we can't really help with what you're doing.